# C# How to directly save Rich Text Box's text into rtf without Dialog Box?

Tags: c#

I have a rich text box and I have also a specific button for the rich text box, which when when clicked, should save the text into rtf format at a specific location.

I Googled but didn't find the appropriate solution to achieve the file saving without using any dialog box!

I hope that I find some help here, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The only purpose of dialog box during saving or loading files is to get heir location. If you have to use specific location - you can end up with a simple constant somewhere in your code. Just make sure that you have escaped slashes.

```
const string fileLocation = @"C:\Folder\file.rtf";
```

So, if you are using WinForms, then you can use [RichTextBox.SaveFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bf5hy2e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
richTextBox1.SaveFile(fileLocation );
```

And if you are using WPF you can use [TextRange.Save](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms598701%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
TextRange t = new TextRange(richTextBox1.Document.ContentStart, richTextBox1.Document.ContentEnd);
using (FileStream file = new FileStream(fileLocation, FileMode.Create))
{
    t.Save(file, System.Windows.DataFormats.Rtf);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use an `OnClick` event and a `StreamWriter`

```
public void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using(var sr = new StreamWriter(@"C:\MyFilePath\file.rtf"))
    {
        sr.Write(rtf.Rtf);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter("c:\\test\\test.rtf");
file.WriteLine(this.richTextBox1.Rtf);
file.Close();
```

Make sure you use .Rtf as .Text will not include Rich Text formatted codes.